# Crash with Singleton Class

Tags: android, crash-reports

I launched my first Android application last week. Some crashes have been reported in Google Dev Console.

Of them is a **java.lang.RuntimeException** caused by a **java.lang.NullPointerException** on the following line:

```
mNoJokersGameVersion = GameData.getInstance().ismNoJokersGameVersion();
```

The class GameData is implemented as a Singleton:

```
public class GameData {

private Boolean mNoJokersGameVersion;

private static GameData mInstance = null;

//Constructor is private because GameData class is a singleton
private GameData() {
    mNoJokersGameVersion = null; 
}

//(Only) This function gives access to the singleton GameData
public static GameData getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new GameData();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public Boolean ismNoJokersGameVersion() {
        return mNoJokersGameVersion;
}

public void setmNoJokersGameVersion(Boolean mNoJokersGameVersion) {
    if (this.mNoJokersGameVersion != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("mNoJokersGameVersion was already set");
    }
    this.mNoJokersGameVersion = mNoJokersGameVersion;
}
```

}

On the creation of the first Activity, setmNoJokersGameVersion is called with the value read from a .xml configuration file:

```
Boolean jokers_version_off = Integer.valueOf(getValue("jokers", element2)) == 0;

GameData.getInstance().setmNoJokersGameVersion(jokers_version_off);
```

What could go wrong ?

**Important note:** the crash happened a few times, not always. Is the Garbage Collector responsible for that?

Is switching from Boolean to boolean inside the class GameData a possible fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is referring to your `Boolean` and not the singleton instance. You set the initial value of the boolean to null, so what is probably happening is your `GameData` got created but the boolean didn't get set yet. Changing to the primitive type boolean with a default value should fix this.

A possible scenario that might lead to this is for instance an orientation change. This will delete nullify the GameData object forcing it to be recreated (when calling `getInstance()`). But the Boolean might not be set the next time you access it.

Comment: OK I will fix this! But I still can not understand how this is caused. Because my app is downloaded in over 2000 devices, and I have only a few crashes like this one. Hardware is so important for such case ?

Comment: @odysseasg Since I can't see your entire source code it's hard to pinpoint the exact cause. Do you see a specific device that has this bug? if not, it could be a strange circumstance. For instance people receiving a call when they are using your app.

Comment: No I don't see a specific device. OK I see. Anyway, thanks for your time!